# Convert list of lists to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert a list of lists to a list of dictionaries. I have a way to do it but I suspect there's a better way:

```
t = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[{keys[0]:l[0], keys[1]:l[1], keys[2]:l[2]} for l in t]
```

with output

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}]
```

This could be done with a loop, but I bet there's a function to do it even easier. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380073/list-of-lists-to-list-of-dictionaries) I'm guessing there's a way to do it with the `map` command, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with the [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[dict(zip(keys, l)) for l in t ]
```

Demo

```
>>> d = [dict(zip(keys, l)) for l in t ]
>>>
>>> d
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be solved with a dictionary comprehension, this way:

```
>>> [{k:v for k,v in zip(keys, l)} for l in t]
[{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}, {'c': 6, 'b': 5, 'a': 4}]
```

Comment: Well, `{k: v for k,v in zip(x, y)}` is really just the explicit, long version of `dict(zip(x, y))`...