# Creating a list of dictionaries from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

My question is on how to create a list of dictionaries from a list of lists, and is a deviation from this question [Dict Comprehension python from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612230/dict-comprehension-python-from-list-of-lists) and this question [List of Lists to List of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380073/list-of-lists-to-list-of-dictionaries)

I have a very long pandas data frame with latitudes and longitudes as such

```
     LAT        LON
     40         5
     40         6
     41         5
     42         8
     42         9
```

I managed to transform it into a list of lists with towers.values(towers is the name of the dataframe) in which each list is of the format [lat,lon]

My goal is to have

```
list_dict = [{'lat': 40, 'lon': 5}, 
             {'lat': 40, 'lon': 6}, 
             {'lat': 41, 'lon': 5},
             {'lat': 41, 'lon': 5},
             {'lat': 42, 'lon': 8},
             {'lat': 42, 'lon': 9}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, try `towers.to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_dict = [{'lat': df.loc[i, 'Lat'], 'lon' : df.loc[i, 'Lon']} for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

As @yatu proposed,  It's much more efficient to use the `df.loc` than a chained index.

---

```
data = zip(df['Lat'].tolist(), df['Lon'].tolist())
[{'lat': a, 'lon': b} for a, b in data]
```

Comment: Chained indexing is discouraged in the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @yatu Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over each row of dataframe can give the solution.

```
res_list_of_dict = [{'lat':i[1][0], 'long':i[1][1]} for i in df.iterrows()]
```